# Alert message ok/cancel from standard button fire trigger

Tags: javascript, standard-objects, button

EDIT:

I have a standard button added to the salesforce standard page, what I want to do when the user clicks on the buttons the following:

```
1) alert with the message saying " are you sure you want to run "
   a. if the user ok then execute the trigger
   b. if the user cancel then do nothing.
```

Is there any way to set up an alert message when a user clicks the button on the Contact object, so when the user clicks on the button, user should get an alert with [ok] and [cancel] if the user click on [cancel] nothing happens but if the user clicks on [ok] then I have to fire trigger event.

Comment: Could you please be more specific?

Comment: Updated please have a look at it.

Comment: Do you mean a custom button you created (Setup > Customize > Contacts > Custom Buttons, Links, and Actions), or a standard button like New, Edit, Delete, Sharing?

Comment: `Custom Button or Link` created with Behavior - Javascript

Comment: Do you just want to run an empty update? Are you looking for the `window.confirm` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm)? How is this not just a pure JS question?

Comment: @AdrianLarson: you are correct, i forgot that i need to pass Contact Id along when I execute the trigger? yes window.confirm method i'm talking about, I haven't work this before. please bare with me :)

Comment: You'd probably just be better off writing a VF Page that directly uses the `Apex` methods you would like to run. Or simpler yet, why not just train your users to click `Edit` then `Save`?

Comment: I do not have control over training the users but back to the question, is it not possible to fire the trigger from the custom buttons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a basic level, you can use JavaScript, as follows:

```
{!RequireScript('/soap/ajax/37.0/connection.js')}
{!RequireScript('/soap/ajax/37.0/apex.js')}

if(confirm('Are you sure?')) {
    var result = sforce.apex.execute('MyClass','MyMethod',{ recordId: '{!Contact.Id}' });
    window.top.location.reload();
}
```

See the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/) for more information.

---

You could also perform a direct DML operation:

```
{!RequireScript('/soap/ajax/37.0/connection.js')}
var record = new sforce.SObject('Contact');
record.Id = '{!Contact.Id}';
if(confirm('Are you sure?')) {
    var result = sforce.connection.update([record]);
    window.top.location.reload();
}
```

Comment: Although this approach requires you to make your methods `global`, right? Couldn't you just do an empty update instead and avoid that?

Comment: @AdrianLarson A decent point. There's several ways to do the same thing, it's mostly a matter of preference. Global/public doesn't make any difference unless we're talking about putting out a managed package. I've included the empty-update method as well.

Comment: Well, you have to make it `webservice` too, which I missed. Doesn't have any impact though? Can't your code then be called from a broader array of contexts? I always thought it would weaken your security somewhat to make methods `global`, depending on what actions they perform.

Comment: @AdrianLarson There's really no practical difference to a beginning developer. Once you start dealing with managed packages, then you have to worry about the limitations imposed by global.

Comment: So basically you just worry about being tied to a specific implementation? Is that it?

Comment: @AdrianLarson For most normal developers, going one way or the other isn't tied to anything. There's no practical difference between either method. I guess using sforce.connection.update is a bit handier, as there's no extra server-side code.

Comment: 1+Thank you sfdcfox this will make me going.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you could accomplish this depending on what you want to do when the button is pressed. 
I have used javascript for easy field updates on the record, and creating a javascript window with ok/cancel buttons shouldn't be too hard. 
Start Here:
http://www.cloudsocius.com/salesforce-opportunity-custom-button/

If you want to get more complex, such as submitting a record for approval. I recommend you look at using flowdesigner. A flow can store information, submit records, create new records, etc.

Comment: Link only answers are frowned upon here, and often get flagged for deletion. Can you add the relevant content to your post?